# Subtypes are not generated into schema when base class is not annotated with @JsonSubTypes

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

No sub type schemas are generated when my Jackson model (base/parent class) is not using the `@JsonSubTypes` or the @Schema(subTypes = ...) annotation to declare all child types.

But,  I can't add that annotation as more sub types are registered at runtime (during startup) with Jackson's object mapper.
This is done using a Spring Bean that creates a Jackson module that does a classpath scan for model types (basically it scans for classes with JsonTypeName annotation).

**Is it possible to add that inheritance information using springdoc API and/or swagger API?**

```kotlin
data class SubtypesRequest(val elements: List<Parent>)

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonTypeName("parent")
open abstract class Parent(val name: String)

@JsonTypeName("childX")
@Schema(allOf = [Parent::class])
class ChildX(name: String, val x: String) : Parent(name)

@JsonTypeName("childY")
@Schema(allOf = [Parent::class])
class ChildY(name: String, val y: String) : Parent(name)
```

The above code only generates the schema for the `Parent` type as it looks like springdoc/swagger doesn't know (can't know) about the sub types `ChildX`, `ChildY`. But really it should be the types `ChildX` and `ChildY` that are the types allowed as types for list elements.

```yaml
    Parent:
      required:
        - name
        - type
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        type:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
    SubtypesRequest:
      required:
        - elements
      type: object
      properties:
        elements:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
```

With the annotated sub types it works

```kotlin
data class SubtypesRequest(val elements: List<Parent>)

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildX::class, name = "childX"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildY::class, name = "childY"),
)
@Schema(subTypes = [ChildX::class, ChildY::class])
@JsonTypeName("parent")
open abstract class Parent(val name: String)
@JsonTypeName("childX")
@Schema(allOf = [Parent::class])
class ChildX(name: String, val x: String) : Parent(name)

@JsonTypeName("childY")
@Schema(allOf = [Parent::class])
class ChildY(name: String, val y: String) : Parent(name)
```

```yaml
    ChildX:
      required:
        - name
        - x
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object
          properties:
            x:
              type: string
    ChildY:
      required:
        - name
        - 'y'
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object
          properties:
            'y':
              type: string
    Parent:
      required:
        - name
        - type
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        type:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
    SubtypesRequest:
      required:
        - elements
      type: object
      properties:
        elements:
          type: array
          items:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ChildX'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ChildY'
```

I have been playing around with manually creating Schema objects and registering them with OpenAPI in many different variations without any results. Below is just one of the last attempts.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class OpenApiConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun openApi(): OpenAPI {
        val api = OpenAPI()

        val parent = ModelConverters.getInstance().read(Parent::class.java)
        val childX = ModelConverters.getInstance().read(ChildX::class.java)
        val childY = ModelConverters.getInstance().read(ChildY::class.java)

        api.schema("Parent", parent.values.first())
        api.schema("ChildX", childX.values.first())
        api.schema("ChildY", childY.values.first())

        return api
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After I while of more investigation and reading the source code I was finally able to find the solution.

A OpenApiCustomizer is required to add schemas

```
@Configuration
class OpenApiConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun openApiCustomizer(): OpenApiCustomiser? {
        return OpenApiCustomiser { openApi: OpenAPI ->
            val schemas =
                openApi.components.schemas

            val converters = ModelConverters.getInstance()

            converters.readAllAsResolvedSchema(Parent::class.java).apply {
                schemas[schema.name] = schema
            }
            converters.readAllAsResolvedSchema(ChildX::class.java).apply {
                schemas[schema.name] = schema
            }
            converters.readAllAsResolvedSchema(ChildY::class.java).apply {
                schemas[schema.name] = schema
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the types should be annotated with `@Schema`. In case a type is a subtype, the annotation's `allOf` value should reference the super type.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar situation because I use a Kotlin sealed class for my parent type, and @JsonSubTypes is unnecessary in this case. Your solution solved the problem that my subtypes were not being generated into my schema.